# Pandas: Split a string from within the middle of a column in Pandas and create a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I split out or extract the 1st number sequence (ie., 200828) from a string in a Python Pandas Dataframe column ['Contract'] and add it as a new column ['Temp'] to the Dataframe and throw the rest away? Note: The preceding letters of the desired number sequence can have 1,2, 3 or 4 characters (ie., A, AA, ABT, ADBE).

```
      Contract
1     ABT200828C00087000              
2    ADBE200828C00550000
```

Comment: Try `df["Contract"].str.extract("(\d+)")`?

Comment: Thanks so Much! It worked. Spent days. I'll have to read up on the Regex Characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a few options. The ones suggested by Chris and Sushanth can be used. You can also use `df['Contract'].str.contains('204')` to get a boolean value. Wrap it with the dataframe to get the records you are looking for.

Here's a sample code I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[8,12,14,16],
                   'Contract':['A2042','Ball2043','Cold2052','Dance2054'],
                   'col3':[True, False, False, True]})
print(df)

d1 = df[df['Contract'].str.contains('204')]

print(d1)
```

**Output is:**

In the below example, I am searching for string '204' and if found, create a record in the new DataFrame `d1`

Original DataFrame:

```
   col1   Contract   col3
0     8      A2042   True
1    12   Ball2043  False
2    14   Cold2052  False
3    16  Dance2054   True
```

New DataFrame:

```
   col1  Contract   col3
0     8     A2042   True
1    12  Ball2043  False
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not want to  have to type in a string. Chris's post was more dynamic.